# Unexpected "onmouseover" behavior with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, onmouseover

I have a "onmouse over" even binded to **all** elements of the page. When the mouse is over an element, it draws a red border to the closest upper relevant element (try [aardvark](http://karmatics.com/aardvark/bookmarklet.html) for an example).

I have the follwing code :

```
<p>
<img height="333" width="250" title="Image par hyperbolic pants explosion sous licence CC - http://www.flickr.com/photos/74502564@N00/2716444681/" class="illustred" src="context-selector-test_files/rha_20090929_antivirus.jpg" />
Ah là là... ces abrutis qui continuent à refuser d'installer des antivirus parce que "
<em>
Je ne télécharge pas !
</em>
" ou "
<em>
Je ne vais que sur des sites de confiance.
</em>
</p>
```

You can see that the "img" is inside the "P".

The expected behavior is that when I go over "P", it get bordered, then when I go to the "IMG", the border go to the "IMG".

It doesn't.

The problem is not CSS because I don't use CSS, but 4 divs to simulate 4 borders in position "absolute" around an element. This is a mandatory for what comes next.

The problem occurs when I go over the "IMG", "mouseover" is indeed triggered, but immidiatly after, "mouse over" is triggered again on "P". I would understand "P -> IMG" but "IMG -> P" bugs me. And why, 2 mouseover in one row? I didn't move the mouse.

Now, what I am missing?

Specs :

- html 4;
- css 2;
- jquery 1.3;
- firefox 3.5;
- ubuntu 9.04;
- coffee 1.50 (l).

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop event propagtion in your mouseover handler.

```
$('selector').mouseover( function(e) {
    ...
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

You also might want to think about using the [hover()](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) method or the [hoverIntent()](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin.  The latter will help to reduce any flashing as you simply drag your mouse across the page by enforcing a timed wait before the event handler is invoked.

Comment: Even better, using e.stopPropagagtion().

Answer (score 1):

You're being caught out by Event Bubbling.

Use [mouseenter()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseenter) instead of [mouseover](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseover).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I wanna kill myself, but here is the answser.

I stupidely forgot to stop the event propagation. You callback function, the one called when "onmouseover" is triggered, must of course return whether has done it's job or not. Return "false" if you don't want the event to be bubbled any upper.

Now, after spending 3 hours on the subject, would you excuse me, I have to hang myself. Cheers.

P.S : I bequeath all my SO rep to the Community Wiki.